# Show/hide h:inputText on selection of h:selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf, ajax4jsf

I'm using JSF 1.1 and Ajax4jsf. I want to show/hide a `<h:inputText>` on change value of a `<h:selectOneMenu>` element named "Colors".

For example, if I select "Red" value in `<h:selectOneMenu>`, then show a `<h:inputText>` for the intensity of the color selected in `<h:selectOneMenu>` (high, medium, low).

I'm not sure whether to use Ajax4jsf or plain JavaScript. I would prefer to use Ajax4jsf, but it is too basic.

Comment: What is your question? :) Are you not sure about using ajax4jsf?

Comment: @IvanYatskevich: My question es: ¿How Hidden/Shows a h:inputText in a form to change value in a h:selectOneMenu element named "Colors" (onchange event) with JSF1.1 and ajax4jsf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`<a4j:support/>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_support.html). This tag gives you an ability to handle various client-side events including `onchange` event.

Consider an example (taken from the link above):

```
<h:form id="planetsForm">
  <h:outputLabel value="Select the planet:" for="planets" />

  <h:selectOneMenu id="planets" value="#{planetsMoons.currentPlanet}" valueChangeListener="#{planetsMoons.planetChanged}">
      <f:selectItems value="#{planetsMoons.planetsList}" />
      <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="moons" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>

  <h:dataTable id="moons" value="#{planetsMoons.moonsList}" var="item">
     <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
     </h:column>
  </h:dataTable> 
</h:form>
```